# If else Condition in R based on different columns and rows

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, conditional-statements, data-transform

I have a dataset with an ID column with multiple visits for every ID. I am trying to create a new variable Status, which will check the Visit column and Value column. The conditions are as follows

For visit in 1,2 & 3, if the values are 1,1,1 then 1
For visit in 1,2 & 3, if the values are 0,1,1 then 0
For visit in 1,2 & 3, if the values are 0,0,0 then 0

How do I specify this condition in R ?

Below is a sample dataset

| ID | Visit | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 |

Result dataset

| ID | Visit | Value | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 | 0 |

Answer (score 1):

I'd have tried something like this (suppose your initial table is called `df`):

```
status = c()
for(i in 1:4){ #1:4 correspond to the ID you showed us
   if(sum(df[df$ID == i,'value'])==3) status=c(status,rep(1,3))
    
   if(sum(df[df$ID == i,'value'])!=3) status=c(status,rep(0,3))
}

df = cbind(df,status)
```

I hope that it will help you

Comment: Thank you, I took your approach via Sum and applied it via dplyr

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `case_when` from the `dplyr` package is what you need to use. Here more details on that fuction: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html